# How can I optimize async.js API calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I'm using async.concat to conduct API calls.  I'm using this instead of other async.js functions because:

A. I need my results in 1 array after all calls are complete

B. async.concat conducts calls in parallel, and performance is important w/ this program

The problem: there doesn't seem to be a simple way to limit concurrent connections.  The program might need to make ~100-300 distinct API calls (I have no way of knowing exact # before 1st API call), and I don't want to slam the server.

I've considered:

1. Nesting the concat() in an async.doWhilst(), and performing chunks of 5-10 @ a time. But that feels a little too jerry-rigged for a problem I'm sure someone's solved before.
2. I could also use one of the async functions w/ a Limit option, and simply pushing each result to an array above the functions' scope.  Should I be worried about multiple API calls trying to push to the same array simultaneously? or does single-threading mean that's not an issue?

Are there other simple & performant avenues here? So long as it's fast and I'm left w/ 1 array of all objects, i'm unopinionated on most other factors here.

Comment: [`Promise`s](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)?

Comment: are they typically more performant? i'd thought they were just syntactically diff't/easier to reason about

Comment: Yes, node's single threaded model means that no 2 API calls will push the result to the array at the same time. Also, all your API calls will process the results concurrently, but not in parallel and you shouldn't be worried about a `race condition`. At least not here and on this level.

Comment: @eAbi - thanks, i'd known node was single-threaded, but hadn't considered how that impacted this topic--this explains a lot.  so, executing 100 API calls "in parallel" is maybe a misnomer--it sounds more like the calls are issued in serial, the responses are awaited in parallel, and the results are processed in series--is that accurate?  If so, it sounds like there's a de facto throttle on API calls already.

Comment: @Brandon Yes, you got it right. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you need, `node'js` seems to be quite a good tool to do it. If you're talking about ~100-300 API requests, you won't have a problem making the requests from `node` so slaming the requestor server (in this case `node`) is not an issue.

But, if you're doing those API calls to the same server that must process those calls, you might have a problem so in this case you should limit the number of calls in batches if optimal number of requests.

Using [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) promise library:

```
// mock data
// supposing that this is the array of apis to call
var requestsToComplete = [c1, c2, c3, ..., c300];

var Promise = require('bluebird');
var results = [];

var fakeCounter = 0;
// fake api call... for demonstration purposes
function processApiCall(apiData) {
    // simulate api call...
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() { resolve(fakeCounter++) });
    });
    return promise;
}

function processBatch(reqs, batchSize, skip) {
    var batchRequests = [];
    for (var i = skip; i < Math.min(i+batchSize, reqs.length); i++) {
        var requestPromise = processApiCall(reqs[i]);
        batchRequests.push(requestPromise);
    }
    // process all 
    return Promise.all(batchRequests);
}

function makeApiCalls() {
    var batchCount = 0;
    var batchSize = 10;
    var promise = Promise.resolve();
    while (batchCount < requestsToComplete.length) {
        batchCount += batchSize;
        promise = promise.then(function() {
             return processBatch(requestsToComplete, batchSize, batchCount);
        }).then(function(batchResponse) {
             results = results.concat(batchResponse);
        });
    }

    promise.then(function() {
        // all api calls finished
        // results now contain all the responses in order of calling, i.e.
        results = [c1Response, c2Response, ..., c300Response];

        // well, in our case results will be an array of fake results...
        results = [0, 1, 2, ..., 300];
    });
}
```

Please note that my above code was not tested, and is just an example of how I would've handled this situation.

But of course, if calling all 300 endpoints at the same time is not a problem, then you can just do:

```
 var promises = [];
 for (... iterate through api endpoints) {
     promises.push(processEndpoint(endpoints[i]));
 }
 Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
     // results will be an array with each response, in order of calling
 })
```